# Failed to check for updates: Error: Service workers are disabled or not supported by this browser

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

Service Worker in Angular send error in console about it not registered. I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngindia-angular-service-worker-l89yrk?file=src/app/app.module.ts) code. In console logged errors. I have no ideas how to fix it.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A code added on title description (linked in word stackblitz)